# Theater row brainteaser

Tags: probability

I bumped into this brainteaser

[*The Theater Row: Eight elegible bachelors and seven beautiful models happen randomly to have purchased single seats in the same 15-seat row of a theater. On the average, how many pairs of adjacent seats are ticketed for marriageable couples?*](http://www.stanford.edu/~kriss1/uploads/1/3/7/7/13777035/splash_spring_2011.pdf)

The solution is $7*7/15$. However, I do not get the explanation.
I tried to work out some pattern by looking at a case with less no. of seats but that did not help as the number of available bachelors and models decreases as get get seated.

Thanks...

Comment: You would get different answers in Delaware and Tennessee.

Comment: In my country, it would be 14.

Comment: Are the models also single?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $15-1=14$ pairs of seats in the row.

Consider one of them.  The probability the left-hand seat of the pair has a man and the right-hand seat has a woman is $\frac8{15} \times  \frac7{14}$ as is the probability  the right-hand seat of the pair has a man and the left-hand seat has a woman.  Combining these gives a probability of $\frac{8}{15}$ that the pair is mixed-sex.

The expected number of mixed-sex pairs is $14$ times this probability since expectation is linear.  So it is $\frac{14 \times 8 }{15} = 7.46666\ldots$.  This is more than double your $ 7 \times 7 / 15$ but it is $ 7 + 7 / 15$, i.e. the $7\frac7{15}$ in your link.

If you have $m$ of one type and $w$ of the other type and $s=m+w$ seats then this becomes $\dfrac{2mw}{m+w}.$

Comment: Thanks. What I do not understand is: if $n$ is the number of pairs, $E(n) = \sum_1^{14} n*p(n)$. I suppose the probability of drawing a couple is not constant, as people one after the other find a seat. Why am I wrong there?

Comment: You are correct that the pairs are not independent.  But that does not affect the additivity of expectation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity